Fitting a cubic equation
Can you suggest some material, some book or research paper, which focuses on finding the best fit cubic equation of the form $y=a(x-b)(x-c)^2$. I have tried on Scopus and SciFinder, however it was of no use. I have some points for fitting this equation (there are some more constraints also)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

DIY. Why not work through the (constrained) least squares approach?

Welcome to Math SE. As the previous comment points out, questions must be specific and detailed enough to allow solid answers. Please feel free to edit your post and add such detail.

Also, it is expected here that mathematical text be formatted with MathJax. Since you’re new here, I have edited your post to use MathJax. For guidance on using it yourself check out the article at our Help Center.

I have tried all the standard techniques, all the curves obtained were very bad as far as RMSE is concerned. Also, additional constraints are: b<0, c<0
